# How to tell `xargs` to ignore empty stdout?

Tags: xargs

How can this code be changed so as not to issue an error, in other words not execute the code after `xargs` if stdout is empty.

**Terminal:**

```
$ cat << EOF > dummy.sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash
[[ -f "\$1" ]] &&  echo "file=\$1" || { echo "error"; exit 1; } 
shift 
(( \$# == 0 )) || "\$0" "\$@" 
EOF
$ chmod +x dummy.sh
$ mkdir trash.later && touch trash.later/foo
$ find trash.later -type f | xargs -n 1 ./dummy.sh 
file=trash.later/foo
$ find trash.later -type f | grep 'bar' | xargs -n 1 ./dummy.sh 
error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `xargs` on the output of `find`. `xargs` by default expects the arguments on input to be delimited in a format that no command outputs, certainly not `find`. The output of `find -print` is also not post-processable reliably.

The only way to use `find` with `xargs` sort-of-reliably is by using the `-print0` and `-0` non-standard extensions (initially from GNU `find`/`xargs`, but nowadays found in many other implementations).

GNU `xargs` also has a `-r` / `--no-run-if-empty` extension to not run the command if the input is empty (some `xargs` implementations such as the one on NetBSD do that by default).

So here, with GNU `find`/`xargs`/`grep` or compatible, you could do:

```
find trash.later -type f -print0 |
  grep -z bar |
  xargs -r -0 -n 1 ./dummy.sh
```

But that has no advantage over the standard:

```
find trash.later -path '*bar*' -type f -exec ./dummy.sh {} ';'
```

(where `-path '*bar*'` looks for `bar` anywhere in the file path like your `grep bar` attempted to do. Replace with `-name '*bar*'` to look for `bar` in the file name only (the last component of its path)).

More reading on that at [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

---

As a more general answer to your question, for `xargs` implementations that do not support `-r` / `--no-run-if-empty`, the work around is to use a `sh` wrapper.

Instead of:

```
... | xargs -n1 cmd
```

do:

```
... | xargs sh -c 'for file do cmd "$file"; done' sh
```

That still runs `sh` if there's no input, but since the list of arguments is empty, there will be no pass in the loop, so `cmd` won't be run.

See also the `ifne` command from `moreutils` which only runs the command if the input is non-empty

```
... | ifne xargs -n1 cmd
```

However note that if the input is not empty but only contains blank lines, `ifne` will run `xargs` but `xargs` will still consider its input has no argument and still run `cmd` once without argument (except on NetBSD).

For completeness

```
... | xargs -I {} cmd {}
```

will also not run `cmd` if the input is empty / blank. In that case, the splitting of the input into arguments is different: leading blanks are removed, quotes are still processed (in `xargs`'s very own unique way), but otherwise arguments are whole lines instead of blank separated words.

Comment: "xargs sh -c 'for file [in $1;] do cmd "$file"; done' sh" I tried both way, it works.

Comment: @Erwann, `for file in $1` would be wrong. That's applying split+glob on the contents of the first positional parameter. Possibly you meant `xargs -n1 sh -c '[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || cmd "$1"' sh`, but it's wasting resource to run one `sh` per argument when `sh` is well able to process more than one at once.

Comment: Just to reiterate, `find ... | xargs sh -c 'for file do cmd "$file"; done' sh` is **not** what you want to do, it will fail if file names contain blanks or newlines or quotes or backslashes... IMO the `find ... | xargs` idiom should be banned (at least when not using NUL-delimited records).

Comment: "when not using NUL-delimited records" or `xargs -I {} ...`, right?

Comment: @Erwann, no, as I said `xargs -I {}` will still not work with filenames containing quotes, backslashes or newline (or that start with blanks, though that doesn't apply to your case where file paths start with `trash.later/`)